# Mahout Benchmark

Tags: linux, mahout, naivebayes

I find it hard to understand how I can interact with Mahout. I have this testcode to train and test with a naives Bayes classification.
I want to measure the time it takes to train and I want to read the accuracy value out of my output file. I have no real clue how to read the output file or measure the time taken to learn in a good manner (so I can maybe run this script automaticly 10 times for example). Any help is appreciated!

```
export WORK_DIR=/user/hue/Bayes-Test/newTestData
mahout seqdirectory -i ${WORK_DIR}/data-all -o ${WORK_DIR}/data-seq -ow 
mahout seq2sparse -i ${WORK_DIR}/data-seq -o ${WORK_DIR}/data-vectors -lnorm -nv -wt tfidf
mahout split -i ${WORK_DIR}/data-vectors/tfidf-vectors  --trainingOutput ${WORK_DIR}/train-vectors  --testOutput ${WORK_DIR}/test-vectors -randomSelectionPct 99  --overwrite --sequenceFiles -xm sequential 
mahout trainnb -i ${WORK_DIR}/train-vectors -el -o ${WORK_DIR}/model -li ${WORK_DIR}/labelindex -ow -c
mahout testnb -i ${WORK_DIR}/test-vectors -m ${WORK_DIR}/model -l ${WORK_DIR}/labelindex -ow -o ${WORK_DIR}/output-testing -c
```

Comment: You should upgrade your Mahout version to 0.11.1.  The `trainnb -el` option was removed in Mahout 0.10.0, and before 0.10.0, there was a bug in the  `-c` option to train a complementary model.

Answer (score 0):

`mahout testnb` will display a confusion matrix and classification statistics of a trained model's performance on given dataset.  It does not actually output any file to a directory.

The `-o ${WORK_DIR}/output-testing` argument that you've supplied is actually unused so this:

```
mahout testnb -i ${WORK_DIR}/test-vectors -m ${WORK_DIR}/model -l ${WORK_DIR}/labelindex -ow -o ${WORK_DIR}/output-testing -c
```

should be changed to:

```
mahout testnb -i ${WORK_DIR}/test-vectors -m ${WORK_DIR}/model -l ${WORK_DIR}/labelindex -c
```

This will display a confusion matrix and some statistics- something like the following:

```
=======================================================
Statistics
-------------------------------------------------------
Kappa                                       0.8523
Accuracy                                   88.6853%
Reliability                                84.3296%
Reliability (standard deviation)            0.2171
Weighted precision                          0.8874
Weighted recall                             0.8869
Weighted F1 score                           0.8846
```

So if you want to make multiple runs, to test wall clock time or accuracy or both, you can pipe the stderr/stdout of your (adjusted) script to a text file and take eg. the average accuracy over the number of runs (by grepping for "Accuracy", etc).   If you're not looking to measure the wall clock time of the entire pipeline, I would suggest only running `seqdirectory` and `seq2sparse` once, since these steps eat up alot of time, and looping `split` `trainnb` and `testnb`.

A couple of adjustments to your script:

```
export WORK_DIR=/user/hue/Bayes-Test/newTestData
mahout seqdirectory -i ${WORK_DIR}/data-all -o {WORK_DIR}/data-seq -ow 
// use either -lnorm -n 2 (log L2 length normalization) or no normalization
mahout seq2sparse -i ${WORK_DIR}/data-seq -o ${WORK_DIR}/data-vectors -nv -wt tfidf
// adjust the randomSelectionPct down to 40 for a 60/40 train/test set
mahout split -i ${WORK_DIR}/data-vectors/tfidf-vectors  --trainingOutput ${WORK_DIR}/train-vectors  --testOutput ${WORK_DIR}/test-vectors -randomSelectionPct 40  --overwrite --sequenceFiles -xm sequential 
mahout trainnb -i ${WORK_DIR}/train-vectors -o ${WORK_DIR}/model -li ${WORK_DIR}/labelindex -ow -c
mahout testnb -i ${WORK_DIR}/test-vectors -m ${WORK_DIR}/model -l ${WORK_DIR}/labelindex  -c
```

**Please Note:**
Mahout has a [Spark implementation of Naive Bayes](http://mahout.apache.org/users/algorithms/spark-naive-bayes.html) which can be run both from the command line and [programmatically](http://mahout.apache.org/users/environment/classify-a-doc-from-the-shell.html).  This my be more useful in determining accuracy.